# constexpr function not returning constexpr value?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, tail-recursion, constexpr

I have the function `hash_constexpr` that takes in a `const char*` and returns a hash using a novel algorithm.  The `hash_constexpr` function should be generating the hash at compile time.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<size_t Count>
    inline constexpr size_t countof(const char(&string)[Count])
    {
        return Count - 1;
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct ascii_hash_t
    {
        template<typename L>
        static constexpr T f(L const& data, T hash, size_t i = 0)
        {
            return i < countof(data) ? f(data, (hash & (~0u)) ^ (hash << 7) ^ T(data[i]), i + 1) : hash;
        }
    };

    template<typename T, typename L>
    inline constexpr T generate_ascii_hash(L const& data)
    {
        return detail::ascii_hash_t<T>::f(data, 0);
    }
};

template<size_t Count>
inline constexpr uint32_t hash_constexpr(const char(&string)[Count])
{
    return detail::generate_ascii_hash<uint32_t>(string);
}
```

My issue is that it appears that the `hash_constexpr` function doesn't appear to actually be returning a `constexpr` value.  When I invoke it like so:

```
constexpr uint32_t asd = hash_constexpr("asdasd");
```

I get the following error:

> Constexpr variable 'asd' must be initialized by a constant expression

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT #1:**

Note that this call is working correctly:

```
constexpr int32_t countof_test = detail::countof("hello");
```

**EDIT #2:**

It appears that this call is working correctly as well:

```
constexpr int32_t generate_ascii_hash_test = detail::generate_ascii_hash<int32_t>("asd");
```

Comment: shouldn't `ascii_hash_t::f` be constexpr?

Comment: You just fixed your own bug by making `f constexpr`.

Comment: It is now, just noticed that it wasn't, but I still get the same error. :(

Comment: I don't get the error with your recent fix, and did without it.

Comment: Hm, what compiler are you using?  I'm using XCode 4.6.1's compiler.

Comment: Might be a compiler bug if you're still seeing it.  I'm using a later clang (llvm/trunk 189730).

Comment: Yea, I'm using the Apple LLVM 4.2 compiler, according to my project settings.

Comment: I'm going to download XCode 4.6.3 in hopes that if this is a compiler bug, it will have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the function `ascii_hash_t::f`, for the specific template instantiation is not a `constexpr`.   This prevents you from performing the operation as a `constexpr`.

See http://ideone.com/heFuFP for an example if it working as you expect.

Comment: @cmbasnett:  What compiler are you using?  That example above, and this one http://ideone.com/ZUxXa2 (both from IDEOne) show it working by just making it `constexpr`

Comment: I'm using XCode 4.6.1's compiler.